# mongodb unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, apt, mongodb

When I try to install mongodb (sudo apt-get install mongodb), i get this :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb : Depends: mongodb-dev but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-server (>= 1:2.4.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried apt-get install -f, update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, change repositories... Nothing seems to work.

If try to install depencies manually i have the same king of errors :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-server : Depends: mongodb-clients but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libboost-filesystem1.55.0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libboost-program-options1.55.0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libboost-system1.55.0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libboost-thread1.55.0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgoogle-perftools4 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libsnappy1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libv8-3.14.5 but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried everything (except fresh install) ...

Comment: Please provide: 1.) The version of Debian... Jessie Sid Etc., and the output of 2.) `apt-cache policy mongodb`, `aptitude --simulate install mongodb`, `aptitude --simulate install -f mongodb`

Answer (score 1):

you should install mongodb-org

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

this is the package recommended on mongoDB's site and it's actually the meta-package which means it could contain some of the dependencies that you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB requires installing the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```